# Troubleshooting mongodb service crash

Tags: python, database, mongodb, raspberry-pi, pymongo

I'm running a python program on a raspberry pi (Linux) which logs data into mongodb (using the pymongo module). I'm having trouble understanding when the mongodb service stops running or why it would ever stop.

Right now, I have my program functions set up so that if they fail to access mongodb (get pymongo connection exceptions), they try to restart the service, wait ten seconds and then re-attempt the operation. These functions are recursive like so:

```
def get_database_collection():
     try:
          # code to get document
          return document
     except Exception:
          # code to log exception in my log files
          start_mongo_service()
          get_database_collection()
```

And this is what the start_mongo_service() function looks like:

```
def start_mongo_service():
     try:
          subprocess.call(["sudo", "service", "mongodb", "start"])
          time.sleep(10)
          return True
     except Exception:
          # code to log exception in my log files (Could not start_mongo_service)
          database_logger = logging.getLogger('database_thread')
          database_logger.exception("Could not start_mongo_service")
          time.sleep(10)
          return False
```

Now, I'm aware that catching all exceptions is bad practice, but I do it because I do not want my code to ever crash, and I log any exception that occurs so I can examine the code's behaviour.

So yesterday my program crashed and the error given on console was: MaximumRecursionDepth exceeded, which I'm assuming means it looped 1000 times and still couldn't escape its exception. This is what the program's log looks like:

```
2019-01-15 18:12:50,000 - ERROR - database_thread - Could not start_mongo_service
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gateway-embedded-code/database.py", line 89, in update_status_collection
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'update'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 266, in __init__
  File "pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 641, in __find_node
pymongo.errors.AutoReconnect: could not connect to localhost:27017: [Errno 110] Connection timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gateway-embedded-code/database.py", line 35, in get_database_collection
  File "pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 269, in __init__
pymongo.errors.ConnectionFailure: could not connect to localhost:27017: [Errno 110] Connection timed out
```

The pymongo exceptions above occurred a lot of times, I shortened them for posting here. Then I tried to look at mongodb's own logs in /var/log/mongodb and the last entry was at Jan 15 17:51:54! After that there was nothing in the logs for that day... I guess the service stopped and my program couldn't restart it either so it crashed at 18:12:50...

```
Tue Jan 15 17:51:54.391 [conn11125] end connection 127.0.0.1:53052 (1 connection now open)
Tue Jan 15 17:51:54.393 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:53054 #11126 (2 connections now open)
Tue Jan 15 17:51:54.408 [conn11126] end connection 127.0.0.1:53054 (1 connection now open)
Tue Jan 15 17:51:54.410 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:53056 #11127 (2 connections now open)
Wed Jan 16 04:33:04.994 [signalProcessingThread] got signal 15 (Terminated), will terminate after current cmd ends
Wed Jan 16 04:33:04.994 [signalProcessingThread] now exiting
Wed Jan 16 04:33:04.994 dbexit:
Wed Jan 16 04:33:04.994 [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
Wed Jan 16 04:33:04.994 [signalProcessingThread] closing listening socket: 9
Wed Jan 16 04:33:04.994 [signalProcessingThread] closing listening socket: 10
Wed Jan 16 04:33:04.994 [signalProcessingThread] closing listening socket: 11
Wed Jan 16 04:33:04.994 [signalProcessingThread] removing socket file: /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
Wed Jan 16 04:33:04.994 [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
Wed Jan 16 04:33:04.994 [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: going to close sockets...
Wed Jan 16 04:33:04.994 [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
Wed Jan 16 04:33:04.994 [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: lock for final commit...
Wed Jan 16 04:33:04.994 [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: final commit...
Wed Jan 16 04:33:04.995 [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: closing all files...
Wed Jan 16 04:33:04.995 [conn11127] end connection 127.0.0.1:53056 (1 connection now open)
Wed Jan 16 04:33:04.997 [signalProcessingThread] closeAllFiles() finished
Wed Jan 16 04:33:04.997 [signalProcessingThread] journalCleanup...
Wed Jan 16 04:33:04.997 [signalProcessingThread] removeJournalFiles
Wed Jan 16 04:33:05.053 [conn4] end connection 127.0.0.1:56470 (0 connections now open)
Wed Jan 16 04:33:05.223 [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: removing fs lock...
Wed Jan 16 04:33:05.224 dbexit: really exiting now


***** SERVER RESTARTED *****
      # Everything works fine from this point onwards
```

Today is Jan 16 and all Jan 16 messages were logged when I rebooted the raspberry pi, the program works completely fine now... but this issue continues to occur when I leave it running and check the next day.

My question is, why would this be happening? When does mongo service stop? Why can't I restart it with my function? Can anybody explain what can be deduced from the logs? Could unexpected power disconnects cause mongodb service to not run on startup? Please help me troubleshoot what could be happening and how I can handle it, I don't want my program to crash!

Sorry for the long post, I can provide any more details you require.

Thank you for reading.

EDIT: Just want to clarify where the AttributeError: Nonetype is coming from. Keep in mind that by collection I just mean a document in the database.
I have a function called update_status_collection():

```
 def update_status_collection(the_update):
       try:
            document = get_database_collection(collection_name='status_collection')
            document.update(the_update)
       except Exception:
            database_logger = logging.getLogger('database_thread')
            database_logger.exception('Could not update_status_collection')
            start_mongo_service()
            update_status_collection(the_update)
```

Now for some reason, the get_database_collection function returns a Nonetype to the document variable and that's where the AttributeError exception is raised, because you can't update a Nonetype. Although I am curious how Nonetype is returned when get_database_collection() is recursive as well..... it's gotta return None after it's reached MaximumRecursionDepth right? That's something I have yet to look into.

UPDATE: Okay I was searching through syslogs to find something suspicious and I think I found the point linux stopped mongo, Below are syslogs for Jan 15 (/var/log/syslog):

```
Jan 15 12:12:07 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Stopping An object/document-oriented database...
Jan 15 12:12:08 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Stopped An object/document-oriented database.
Jan 15 12:12:08 raspberrypi rc.local[463]: [967] Failed to execute script __main__
Jan 15 12:12:11 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started An object/document-oriented database.
Jan 15 12:12:11 raspberrypi mongod[2336]: all output going to: /var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log
Jan 15 12:14:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Stopped target Timers.
Jan 15 12:14:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Stopped Daily apt upgrade and clean activities.
Jan 15 12:14:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Stopped target Bluetooth.
Jan 15 12:14:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Stopped Daily apt download activities.
Jan 15 12:14:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Stopping User Manager for UID 1000...
Jan 15 12:14:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Stopped target System Time Synchronized.
Jan 15 12:14:22 raspberrypi vncserver-x11-serviced[453]: XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":0"
Jan 15 12:14:22 raspberrypi vncserver-x11-serviced[453]:       after 14426 requests (14426 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
Jan 15 12:14:22 raspberrypi bluetoothd[524]: Terminating
Jan 15 12:14:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Stopping Bluetooth service...
Jan 15 12:14:22 raspberrypi watchdog[562]: stopping daemon (5.15)
Jan 15 12:14:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Stopping Disk Manager...
Jan 15 12:14:22 raspberrypi udisksd[883]: udisks daemon version 2.1.8 exiting
Jan 15 12:14:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Stopped target Sound Card.
Jan 15 12:14:22 raspberrypi bluetoothd[524]: Stopping SDP server
Jan 15 12:14:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Closed Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status /dev/rfkill Watch.
Jan 15 12:14:22 raspberrypi bluetoothd[524]: Exit
Jan 15 12:14:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Stopping watchdog daemon...
Jan 15 12:14:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Stopping Save/Restore Sound Card State...
Jan 15 12:14:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Unmounting RPC Pipe File System...
Jan 15 12:14:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Stopping Authorization Manager...
Jan 15 12:14:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Stopped Daily Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
Jan 15 12:14:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Stopping Session c1 of user pi.
Jan 15 12:14:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Stopped Getty on tty1.
Jan 15 12:14:22 raspberrypi vncserver-x11-serviced[453]: XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":0"
Jan 15 12:14:28 raspberrypi systemd-modules-load[111]: Inserted module 'i2c_dev'
Jan 15 12:14:28 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Apply Kernel Variables.
Jan 15 12:14:28 raspberrypi fake-hwclock[112]: Tue 15 Jan 12:14:24 UTC 2019
Jan 15 12:14:28 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Time has been changed
Jan 15 12:14:28 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Restore / save the current clock.
Jan 15 12:14:28 raspberrypi systemd-fsck[113]: e2fsck 1.43.4 (31-Jan-2017)
Jan 15 12:14:28 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Create Static Device Nodes in /dev.
Jan 15 12:14:28 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting udev Kernel Device Manager...
Jan 15 12:14:28 raspberrypi systemd-fsck[113]: /dev/mmcblk0p2: clean, 137720/939744 files, 1384356/3809792 blocks
Jan 15 12:14:28 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started File System Check on Root Device.
Jan 15 12:14:28 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Remount Root and Kernel File Systems...
Jan 15 12:14:28 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Remount Root and Kernel File Systems.
Jan 15 12:14:28 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Load/Save Random Seed...
Jan 15 12:14:28 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting udev Coldplug all Devices...
Jan 15 12:14:28 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Flush Journal to Persistent Storage...
Jan 15 12:14:28 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Load/Save Random Seed.
Jan 15 12:14:28 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Flush Journal to Persistent Storage.
Jan 15 12:14:28 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Set the console keyboard layout.
Jan 15 12:14:28 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Reached target Local File Systems (Pre).
Jan 15 12:14:28 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started udev Kernel Device Manager.
Jan 15 12:14:28 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started udev Coldplug all Devices.
Jan 15 12:14:28 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Show Plymouth Boot Screen...
Jan 15 12:14:28 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Found device /dev/serial1.
Jan 15 12:14:28 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Show Plymouth Boot Screen.
Jan 15 12:14:28 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Reached target Encrypted Volumes.
Jan 15 12:14:28 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Reached target Paths.
Jan 15 12:14:28 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Forward Password Requests to Plymouth Directory Watch.
Jan 15 12:14:28 raspberrypi mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 3: "/sys/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.1"
Jan 15 12:14:28 raspberrypi mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 4: "/sys/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.2"
Jan 15 12:14:28 raspberrypi mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 5: "/sys/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4"
Jan 15 12:14:28 raspberrypi mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 4 was not an MTP device
Jan 15 12:14:28 raspberrypi mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 5 was not an MTP device
Jan 15 12:14:28 raspberrypi mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 3 was not an MTP device
Jan 15 12:14:28 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Listening on Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status /dev/rfkill Watch.
Jan 15 12:14:28 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Reached target Sound Card.
Jan 15 12:14:28 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Found device /dev/disk/by-partuuid/f143b93d-01.
Jan 15 12:14:28 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting File System Check on /dev/disk/by-partuuid/f143b93d-01...
```

The first two lines stop the database, the third line "Failed to execute script **main**" is from my program! But immediately afterwards it restarts the database.... Can someone make sense of what happened? It seems a lot of services were stopped and then restarted...

Comment: subprocess.call(["sudo", "service", "mongodb", "start"]) -> Is this the correct command? On my machine I do "sudo service mongod start" (not mongodb)

Comment: Actually, can you just run the start command in a terminal and check the output?

Comment: @Neil Hey, I have used the command on terminal and verified that it works, I found it right here on stackoverflow too, I'll try and find that thread.

Comment: Okay. Do you know what this file is ""gateway-embedded-code/database.py" ? Can you update your post to show how you're logging that exception?

Comment: have you checked /var/log/messages? My first thought might be the OOM killer, but it looks like a SIGTERM rather than a SIGKILL... but services dont get SIGTERMs arbitrarily so I would hope a system log would have some explanation.

Comment: @Neil, yes that is my program file basically. Sure, I am using the python logging module so it's only one line of code.

Comment: Unrelated to the mongo termination -- I would presume the maximum recursion failure is the result of a non-connection-related exception (e.g. AttributeError) triggering your reconnect and recursive call. Then on the each iteration the same AttributeError comes up and takes you an additional step deeper.

Comment: @booleys1012 Yes there is a non-connection related exception as well, I sort of understand the gist of why that is happening but first I want to troubleshoot the connection issue. If you're curious, it's because I try to retrieve a document from the database into a variable, then call .update on that variable. But since the document could not be retrieved, that variable happens to be a Nonetype....

I tried looking through the /var/log/messages but couldn't spot anything mongo related... any specific words I should search for in there?

Comment: Okay I'm not 100% sure what the issue is. But I strongly suspect that you need to make sure that you are logging clearly what is happening when. And yes, that includes not doing a general "except" statement. The trace indicates that the connection problem happens during the handling of the none exception. I.e, the None exception happens first. It might be that your make_connection is then just excepting because it's catching an unrelated issue. I'm not sure. But I  would log the flow of control quite carefully and try and ISOLATE the problem.

Comment: @Neil Hey thanks, I will try and make my logging clearer, I have added an EDIT in my question explaining where the AttributeError is coming from, I hope that helps. Ultimately we're reaching these exceptions because of a connection issue with mongodb I feel...

Comment: @booleys1012 Hey, I found something strange in syslogs! Updated my question, do you know what it could mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has now been solved, when reading my temperature sensor on the raspberry pi using SPI, spi.close() was not being called properly and as a result every spi.open() was resulting in a new spidev file being opened. There's a limit to how many files one process can open, and that limit was being reached in my case in around 6-7 hours, after which the script crashed.

It's also important to note that proper logging was not implemented in this area of the code nor were exceptions properly caught, so the exception "OSError: Too many open files" was not being caught or logged making this a very mysterious issue.

Once the exception was caught, it was an easy fix, by properly adding spi.close() every place where spi was being opened.

You can check how many files your process has opened using:

```
lsof -p <pid_of_your_process>
```

The lsof command was not installed by default on my linux distribution so I used:

```
sudo apt install lsof
```

Now the reason this is related to my pymongo connection exceptions is because in order to make a connection, the pymongo module calls open() on various things like sockets etc, which in turn opens a file. I hypothesize that my program was unable to open these files after six hours, because it had already reached the maximum number of files it could open, and therefore raised the pymongo exceptions.

Hope this helps somebody!